# How to notify the obsever when list changes in Rxjava

Tags: java, swing, rx-java3

I have class three classes. Pref, ClassA, and ClassB.

```
public class Pref{
     public static ArrayList<Pref> prefList;
     public static Observable<ArrayList<Pref>> observable;

     public static void loadData(){
         prefList = getFromDb();
         observable = Observable.just(prefList);
    }  
}
```

Application runs the ClassA First.

```
    public ClassA{
         public ClassA(){
              initObserver();
              setObserver();
         }
         public void initObserver(){
               Pref.loadData();
         }

         public void setObserver(){
              Observer<ArrayList<Pref>> obs = new Observer() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable dspsbl) {
                      System.out.println("Subscribed");
                }

              @Override
              public void onNext(ArrayList<Pref>> t) {
                    System.out.println("Loading Preference.");
                    //Need to do some other works here.
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable thrwbl) {
              }

             @Override
             public void onComplete() {
             }
          };
         Pref.observable.subscribe(obs);
     }
}
```

Now I want to change the list from ClassB.

```
     public class ClassB{
            private void changeList(){
                  Pref.prefList = loadDataFromSomeSource();
           }
     }
```

When I run `ClassA`, the `System.out works` fine. But when I change the list from `ClassB` nothing happens. My question is, is the right way to work with `Rxjava`. Is it for `Rxjava` built? If I am wrong how can I achieve this functionality? How can I write several `ClassA` like classes so that When the `ClassB::changeList()` runs, I can listen it in `ClassA?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `Pref.prefList = loadDataFromSomeSource();`, you assign a new list instance to `Pref.prefList`. This will not update `Pref.observable` in any way, because this still refers to the old `Pref.prefList` instance.

I also think that you can not use an `Observable` to publish events through it. As far as I understand your situation, you need an `ObservableSource` (see http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableSource.html). For example, it is implemented by `PublishSubject`. You could use it like this:

```java
PublishSubject<String> source = PublishSubject.create();
source.subscribe(System.out::println);
source.onNext("test 1");
source.onNext("test 2");
source.onNext("test 3");
```

Or, in your case: in class `Pref`, you can use `public static PublishSubject<ArrayList<Pref>> source = PublishSubject.create();`. When loading the data, you can publish the new data using `onNext`, like this in `ClassB`: `Pref.source.onNext(loadDataFromSomeSource())`